# Azure Table Storage Paging Most Recent

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I working on a project that used Azure Table Storage.  The data is stored in descending order (Row Key) - most recent message first.  The code will pull back the top 10 messages upon the initial request.

Is there any way to use continuation tokens to detect if any new messages have been added?  I plan to use jquery to issue a request every 60 seconds.

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just store the last received rowkey in your javascript and then send that rowkey in the request and use it to check if there are any elements with a rowkey less than that element.